# Clarification on eigenfunction property from Oppenheim's Discrete-time signal processing, 3rd ed

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, frequency-response, self-study, stability

Could anybody explain what is meant  by the following statement on page 50 of Oppenheim and Schafer's book *Discrete-Time Signal Processing* (third edition)?

> The eigenfunction property of complex exponentials depends on stability
> of the system, since at finite $n$, the transient response must have become zero, so that we only see the steady-state response $H(e^{j\omega})e^{j\omega n}$ for all finite $n$.

Comment: It's not clear what you're not clear on.  They're saying that if the system isn't stable it's not going to settle out *at all*, so it's meaningless to say what it'll settle out *to*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement can only be understood given its context. Right before the sentence you quoted, we have this statement:

> It is no surprise that the condition for existence of the frequency
> response is the same as the condition for dominance of the steady-state solution.
> Indeed, a complex exponential that exists for all $n$ can be thought of as one that is applied at $n = -\infty$.

Consequently, starting out at $n=-\infty$, if the system is stable, all transients must have died out at "finite $n$" because at finite $n$ the moment that the exponential was applied is infinitely long ago.

We also depend on stability because otherwise the eigenvalue $H(e^{j\omega})$ wouldn't exist, at least not in the classical sense.

Comment: "It is no surprise that the condition for existence of the frequency response is the same as the condition for dominance of the steady-state solution". This statement is also not clear to me. Could you please prove this?

Comment: @LionelIceberg: Isn't that proved in the equations right before that statement in the book?

Answer (score 0):

In a stable system transient response is not necessarily zero at finite n, it becomes zero as n goes to infinity. Hence, the following statement is not clear to me:

"at finite n, the transient response must have become zero'

Comment: You're right in general, but not if the input signal was applied at $n=-\infty$, i.e., has been existing forever. In that case the transients have died out at finite $n$. That's what the quoted sentence refers to. Also see [my answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/71771/4298).